# Error adding target dependencies with Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

When trying to include a target dependency I get the error: `The manifest describes a target that cannot be found in your source tree: parser`

Here is my Package.swift file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Phoenix",
          targets: [
            Target(
                name: "Phoenix",
                dependencies: [.Target(name: "parser")]),
            Target(
                name: "parser")
    ]
)
```

I am following the format described here: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Package.swift.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you're both right, my actual problem was that my subdirectory didn't contain any swift code so a module wasn't being generated

Comment: Ahh. OK this is a bug. I'll fix it today.

Comment: I can't get this working as my "modules" fail when I import them.
I one of my modules exports native libraries as "submodules" but all those imports fail.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have a `parser` directory?

You should have a layout something like:

```
     .
     └── Sources
         └── Phoenix
         │   └── File1.swift
         └── parser
             └── File2.swift
```

Or:

```
     .
     └── Phoenix
     │   └── File1.swift
     └── parser
         └── File2.swift
```

This instructs SwiftPM to create two modules, one called Phoenix and one called "parser".

Answer (score 1):

The Swift Package Manager documentation you link to states `The targets are named how your subdirectories are named.` If the target `parser` cannot be found, presumably you do not have a subdirectory named `parser` located in the directory where your `Package.swift` file is located.

You should clarify your directory structure so that it can be compared to your `Package.swift` contents.

**Edit**

Max has provided a good example. Note that the 'Sources' dir could also be 'Source', 'src' or 'srcs'